# How can i test if postfix really uses secondary mailserver if first one is not available?

Tags: email, postfix, email-server

when i query for the mailservers of domainx with "dig domainx.com MX" the result is:

> ...
>   ;; ANSWER SECTION:
>   domainx.com.       55188   IN  MX  120 mail2.domainx.com.
>   domainx.com.       55188   IN  MX  100 mail.domainx.com.
>   ...

When the webserver (postfix) sends a mail to someone@domainx.com it uses mail.domainx.com as relay.

Now, i want to test if he really switches to mail2.domainx.com if mail.domainx.com is not available. I have **no access to the mailservers**, just the webserver which is running postfix.

I thought of temporarily making a false entry in /etc/hosts for mail.domainx.com on the webserver - will this work?

Is there another and better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could temporarily add a blackhole route to the primary MX and then observe Postfix's behaviour.

**Linux**

```
ip route add blackhole ip.add.re.ss
```

**Solaris/BSD**

```
route add -host ip.add.re.ss 127.0.0.1 -blackhole
```

Comment: THX - This is a nice solution. Sadly my webserver says "command not found" for route or ip. i think i have to go with the /etc/hosts - version.

Answer (score 2):

Usualy, I test this problematic with the firewall : I put a filter from my server to the IP of mail.domainx.com, on the SMTP port (25/tcp).

Then, Postfix can't join the first server and should try the second.

But I think you can do the same thing with your /etc/hosts proposition, by choosing an IP which doesn't exists.